# Mapping joint histogram values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have asked a similar question ([Mapping values from a joint histogram back into the image spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069888/mapping-values-from-a-joint-histogram-back-into-the-image-spaces)), but I've realized that any points on the JH that has value greater than 1 would NOT be mapped back as the amount of pixels in the image space. For example, if image A and image B have JH value 3 at, say, intensity 3 for A and 6 for B, then that means there are effectively 3 pixels with this information. Here is my (failed) attempt to map back the indices. I should mention images A and B have values between 0 and 255, and the JH has shape 256x256, so the binning is one-to-one, fortunately!

```
import numpy as np 

rows, cols = A.shape[0], B.shape[1]
N = 256 # bins

#### Numpy's method
#H,xedge,yedge = np.histogram2d(A, B, bins=(rows,cols))


#### Manually
H1 = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=float)
inds = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

for i,j in product(range(rows), range(cols)):
    # Keep in mind H[0,0] will be HUGE
    H1[A[i,j], B[i,j]] = H1[A[i,j], B[i,j]] + 1

    # conditionals for saving indices 
    if H1[A[i,j], B[i,j]]>0:
        # omit the point where the intensities are 0 for both 
        if A[i,j]!=0 and B[i,j]!=0:
            inds = np.append(inds, [[A[i,j], B[i, j], i, j, 
                    H1[A[i,j], B[i,j]]]], axis=0)


# omit the first row and sort by the last column, the JH 
# outputs are A, B, i, j, H values
inds = inds[1:]
inds = inds[np.argsort(inds[:, 0])]
```

However if you map values of 1 in the joint histogram using the method linked above, you get something like 3662 values, but this method you get 6507, almost double! I'm a little stumped